# Office Graph TrendingAround API result?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to see what is the result of calling Files Trending around me API (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/trendingAround) but I just get the following:

{{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('071578c7-9961-4b43-970b-66fbbb6a938f')/trendingAround",
  "value": []
}}

If I call Get My Files (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children) I get a list of my files, but I am getting anything calling Files trending around me, and I didn't find any documentation about it, just to see what that API includes.

Can anybody tell me what should be the resoult of it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`trendingAround` is defined as:

```
<NavigationProperty Name="trendingAround" Type="Collection(Microsoft.OutlookServices.driveItem)" ContainsTarget="true" />
```

where `driveItem` is the OneDrive item type. (There are no new properties defined by Microsoft.OutlookServices.) Thus schema-wise, the response from `/me/trendingAround` is compatible with the response from `/me/drive/root/children`.

However, while the 2 responses conform to the same schema, it doesn't mean that they have the same properties populated. The response from `trendingAround` seems to contain fewer properties. Here is a sample response I get:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('...')/trendingAround",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "Drives('...')/items('..')",
      "id": "...",
      "name": "...",
      "DateTimeCreated": "...",
      "DateTimeLastModified": "...",
      "webUrl": "..."
    }
 ]
}
```

Keep in mind that `/me/trendingAround` is not an official API and is subject to change/removal.