# TrendingAround and WorkingWith APIs

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to find what is taken to see "People Working With" and "list trending around". The documentation reads for "working with":
Calculated insight for the list of users that a user has been working with.

For List Trending around: Calculated insight that returns the list of items trending around the user.

I ran both queries and both queries returned no results.

So, how can test this? What are the APIs looking to have results? Do I have to create a group in outlook or something like that?

Comment: You have two separate questions here. You may want to split them. The answer to the API question would be very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051908/office-graph-trendingaround-api-result/37055529#37055529. The answer to the question how to make it work is more difficult - since this is an experimental functionality, I wouldn't be surprised if it's only enabled for certain tenants. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, how can test this? What are the APIs looking to have results? Do I have to create a group in outlook or something like that?

**WorkingWith — People whom you frequently interact with.**

**TrendingAround — Items that are popular in your circle of colleagues**

(From the document [Query the Office Graph using GQL and SharePoint Online Search REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/query-Office-graph-using-gql-with-search-rest-api))

In your test environment, you need to create several users in same department, or work in the same project. Then create several documents in OverDrive for Business.

If you've used [Delve application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Office-Delve-1315665a-c6af-4409-a28d-49f8916878ca) in Office 365, you may find out that the TrendingAround result is the same result in the Delve > Discover documents from people around you.

[image]

[image]